# Why can't statsmodels reproduce my R logistic regression results?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm confused about why my logistic regression models in R and statsmodels do not agree.

If I prepare some data in R with

```
# From https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/15.071x/asset/census.csv
library(caTools) # for sample.split
census = read.csv("census.csv")
set.seed(2000)
split = sample.split(census$over50k, SplitRatio = 0.6)
censusTrain = subset(census, split==TRUE)
censusTest = subset(census, split==FALSE)
```

and then run a logistic regression with

```
CensusLog1 = glm(over50k ~., data=censusTrain, family=binomial)
```

I see [results](https://gist.github.com/orome/9840196) like

```
                                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                              -8.658e+00  1.379e+00  -6.279 3.41e-10 ***
age                                       2.548e-02  2.139e-03  11.916  < 2e-16 ***
workclass Federal-gov                     1.105e+00  2.014e-01   5.489 4.03e-08 ***
workclass Local-gov                       3.675e-01  1.821e-01   2.018 0.043641 *  
workclass Never-worked                   -1.283e+01  8.453e+02  -0.015 0.987885    
workclass Private                         6.012e-01  1.626e-01   3.698 0.000218 ***
workclass Self-emp-inc                    7.575e-01  1.950e-01   3.884 0.000103 ***
workclass Self-emp-not-inc                1.855e-01  1.774e-01   1.046 0.295646    
workclass State-gov                       4.012e-01  1.961e-01   2.046 0.040728 *  
workclass Without-pay                    -1.395e+01  6.597e+02  -0.021 0.983134   
...
```

but of I use the same data in Python, by first exporting from R with

```
write.csv(censusTrain,file="traincensus.csv")
write.csv(censusTest,file="testcensus.csv")
```

and then importing into Python with

```
import pandas as pd

census = pd.read_csv("census.csv")
census_train = pd.read_csv("traincensus.csv")
census_test = pd.read_csv("testcensus.csv")
```

I get errors and strange results that bear no relationship to the ones I get in R.

If I simply try

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

census_log_1 = sm.Logit.from_formula(f, census_train).fit()
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (19187,2) (19187,)
```

Even if prepare the data with `patsy` using

```
import patsy
f = 'over50k ~ ' + ' + '.join(list(census.columns)[:-1])
y, X = patsy.dmatrices(f, census_train, return_type='dataframe')
```

trying

```
census_log_1 = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()
```

results in the same error. The only way I can avoid errors is to use use `GLM`

```
census_log_1 = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
```

but this produces [results](https://gist.github.com/orome/9839624) that are entirely different from those produced by (what I thought was) the equivalent R API:

```
                                                   coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                                       10.6766      5.985      1.784      0.074        -1.055    22.408
age                                             -0.0255      0.002    -11.916      0.000        -0.030    -0.021
workclass[T. Federal-gov]                       -0.9775      4.498     -0.217      0.828        -9.794     7.839
workclass[T. Local-gov]                         -0.2395      4.498     -0.053      0.958        -9.055     8.576
workclass[T. Never-worked]                       8.8346    114.394      0.077      0.938      -215.374   233.043
workclass[T. Private]                           -0.4732      4.497     -0.105      0.916        -9.288     8.341
workclass[T. Self-emp-inc]                      -0.6296      4.498     -0.140      0.889        -9.446     8.187
workclass[T. Self-emp-not-inc]                  -0.0576      4.498     -0.013      0.990        -8.873     8.758
workclass[T. State-gov]                         -0.2733      4.498     -0.061      0.952        -9.090     8.544
workclass[T. Without-pay]                       10.0745     85.048      0.118      0.906      -156.616   176.765
...
```

Why is logistic regression in Python producing errors and different results from those produced by R? Are these APIs not in fact equivalent (I've had them work before to produce identical results)? Is there some additional processing of the datasets required to make them usable by statsmodels?

Comment: I don't see `age` in your statsmodels output ... ?

Comment: Can reproduce the above differences with a small example that can be reproduced?

Comment: @BenBolker: Added. Results were ordered differently in Python.

Comment: @Akavall: Use the [linked data](https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/15.071x/asset/census.csv).

Comment: don't have time to poke in, but my best guess would be a difference in contrasts/dummy coding.  Do you get comparable answers if you use only continuous predictors?

Comment: See also @Ben Bolker's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612577/difference-in-glm-results-between-ipython-and-r

Comment: about the ValueError: y needs to be one dimensional for Logit, depending on the format of the original data, patsy can return a dummy encoding with two columns. The GLM results look like they have the sign reversed, which means 0, 1 encoding is flipped compared to R.

Answer (score 4):

The error is due to the fact that patsy expands the LHS variable to be a full Treatement contrast. Logit does not handle this as indicated in the docstring, but as you see GLM with binomial family does.

I can't speak to the difference in the results without a full output. In all likelihood it's different default handling of categorical variables or you're using different variables. Not all are listed in your output.

You can use logit by doing the following pre-processing step.

```
census = census.replace(to_replace={'over50k' : {' <=50K' : 0, ' >50K' : 1}})
```

Note also that the default solver for logit doesn't seem to work all that well for this problem. It runs into a singular matrix problem. Indeed, the condition number for this problem is huge, and what you get in R might not be a fully converged model. You might try reducing your number of dummy variables.

```
[~/]
[73]: np.linalg.cond(mod.exog)
[73]: 4.5139498536894682e+17
```

I had to use the following to get a solution

```
mod = sm.formula.logit(f, data=census)
res = mod.fit(method='bfgs', maxiter=1000)
```

Some of your cells end up being very small. This is compounded by the other sparse dummy variables.

```
[~/]
[81]: pd.Categorical(census.occupation).describe()
[81]: 
                    counts     freqs
levels                              
?                    1816  0.056789
Adm-clerical         3721  0.116361
Armed-Forces            9  0.000281
Craft-repair         4030  0.126024
Exec-managerial      3992  0.124836
Farming-fishing       989  0.030928
Handlers-cleaners    1350  0.042217
Machine-op-inspct    1966  0.061480
Other-service        3212  0.100444
Priv-house-serv       143  0.004472
Prof-specialty       4038  0.126274
Protective-serv       644  0.020139
Sales                3584  0.112077
Tech-support          912  0.028520
Transport-moving     1572  0.049159
```

Comment: I've linked the full output.

Comment: You have NAs in your R output. My guess is that it's dropping some columns due to multicollinearity, there aren't enough observations in those cells to estimate (kind of the same thing), or your R model has convergence problems that you should check. We don't drop any columns by default. As I mentioned, you can try removing or combining certain categories for your dummy variables. Use describe as I did above to see how sparse your categories are. See my other comments above as well.

Comment: Basically, what you have are modeling and data issues. In ideal circumstances, they should produce the same output, but you're going to have to investigate why they don't. If it's something like R drops a column due to perceived multicollinearity and statsmodels doesn't, then this is something we can look it.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it except that I get a high accuracy in R and the course exercise from which this is taken says "We have just seen how the logistic regression model for this data achieves a high accuracy. Moreover, the significances of the variables give us a way to gauge which variables are relevant for this prediction task." So it's not meant as a garbage model to demonstrate issues with variables. I'd expect both tools to produce the same result.

Comment: BTW, in case it isn't clear. I'm entirely new to R and analytics. I've developed an instant dislike for R and would LOVE to see statsmodels take over. The course I'm taking is taught in R, and I've been working (mostly successfully) to do it in Python, but often hit stumbling blocks like this where I have to drop back into R — which always leaves me feeling a bit dirty.

Comment: "High accuracy" when there are NaNs in the resulting coefficients is suspect to me. To me that indicates there's still modeling work to be done. I didn't actually use your train/test split though. I just used the whole dataset. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1534) to look into this more, but I suspect it's something in the code. The modeling should be the same unless R is doing something subtle.

Comment: Thanks! I make no warranty for the "high accuracy" of the R model; I'm just (naively) quoting the corse materials. I'm glad to hear that the modeling should be the same (at least my expectations are right) and look forward to see what the issue turns up.

Comment: Note: Even if the parameters are not identified and the algorithm picks one solution, then you can still get a good predictor, if the linear combination of explanatory variables is not relevant or stays unchanged in your out of sample cases. (statsmodels does something similar in linear models when we use the generalized inverse, pinv, for the solution.