# Statsmodels - broadcast shapes different?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am attempting to perform a logistic regression on a dataset which contains a target variable which is boolean ('default'), and two features ('fico_interp', 'home_ownership_int') using logit module in statsmodels.  All three values are from the same data frame, 'traindf':

```
from sklearn import datasets
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

lmf = smf.logit('default ~ fico_interp + home_ownership_int',traindf).fit()
```

Which generates an error message:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (40406,2) (40406,)

How can this happen?

Comment: one of the columns `fico_interp` or `home_ownership_int` is a (x,2) array. try to visualize them

Comment: My guess is that the boolean target variable doesn't work. Try to convert it to `int`. patsy treats the boolean as categorical variable and converts it to a 2 dimensional response variable which doesn't work for Logit. There should be already an open issue for this in statsmodels, but there is no solution yet.

Comment: @wajdi Hi Wajdi - that doesn't appear to solve the problem. home_ownership_int is indeed  a categorical variable, but when I substitute a continuous variable, I get the same error message.  I also note that each variable is a dtype 'object' with the same dimensions -  (40407,)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `traindf['default']` contains values that are not numeric.

The following code reproduces the error:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, statsmodels.formula.api as smf
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,2), columns=list('AB'))
df['C'] = ((df['B'] > 0)*1).apply(str)
lmf = smf.logit('C ~ A', df).fit()
```

And the following code is a possible way to fix this instance:

```
df.replace(to_replace={'C' : {'1': 1, '0': 0}}, inplace = True)
lmf = smf.logit('C ~ A', df).fit()
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716521/) reports an analogous issue.